# TcpListener & Socket connection fails

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, tcplistener

My friend runs a simple C# Console Application that starts a TcpListener on Port 8484. This is how it's being done:

```
public static void Listen()
{
    Listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 8484);
    Listener.Start();
    Listener.BeginAcceptSocket(new AsyncCallback(EndAccept), null);
}

public static void EndAccept(IAsyncResult IAR)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Connection accepted on Port 8484.");
    Socket socket = Listener.EndAcceptSocket(IAR);
    Instance = new Client(socket);
    Listener.Stop();
    Listener = null;
}
```

I connect to him using:

```
public void Connect()
{
    _socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    try
    {
        _socket.Connect(IP, Port);

        Debug.WriteLine("Connected with server!");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(TypeName + " [ERROR] Could not connect to server @ {0}:{1}: {2}", IP, Port, ex.Message);
    }
}
```

However, for some reason - he can't accept the connection, it says it doesn't respond. Port 8484 is 100% opened at his computer.

Why does this happen?

Comment: is port 8484 open on your network?

Comment: Where is your friend? On internet WAN or LAN?

Comment: @DiegoCNascimento WAN. And yes, the port IS open.

Comment: @user2714359 how you are sure the port is open? If is just because your friend firewall is disabled or has a rule for it does not mean that. It can be open but can not be reachable externally if it has a NAT. Also, some ISPs block low ports, even that 8484 would be strange to block.

Comment: @DiegoCNascimento We tested the port in various sites and tried a public chat program to use that port on, it is open.

Answer (score 0):

Use telnet to verify connectivity to the remote server. E.g. run the command "telnet ip_address port". If it successfully connects then you can reach the server. If telnet cannot connect then you cannot reach the server, likely due to a firewall issue.

Comment: What if the remote host don't have Telnet Server enabled in Windows Features? Will it still work?

Comment: It wants to connect to your server not Windows Telnet Server. Anyway this does not seems Firewall issue if user is correct in their affirmation, but NAT issue.

Comment: @DiegoCNascimento Well, it said it can't connect.

Comment: But it said it has the ports open, what should say it checked firewall (please). So NAT or ISP could be the question.

Comment: @DiegoCNascimento It works fine with other programs (For example, we succesfuly ran a Java MapleStory server on the same port, so there's no real issue).

Comment: I don't know of that "MappleStory" but seems a multiplayer game. Anyway there's so much thing about it. It can request a entry on the NAT what your program does not, and it can be at a different port that's working. You know what port it uses? And what are the results with telnet?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37468/discussion-between-user2714359-and-diego-c-nascimento)

Comment: @user2714359 Yes there is a real issue. If telnet cannot connect to your server/port and the port is in the "LISTEN" state then the port is being blocked by a firewall or is not accessible. Maybe you should read about telnet instead of telling me I'm wrong in my advice. Your comment about "it works fine with other programs so there's no issue" is wrong because as I said, telnet would connect. It could be that your "other programs" set up port forwarding or firewall rules for themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling the firewall.<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1 - Helped user in chat to test for firewall problems, and it has not open. That has the problem</sup>